# Two ways to show a function is a measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Consider the following function $f:(-\infty,e]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
   1 & ,\text{if } x=e \\
   \ln(x)       & ,\text{if } x \in(0,e)\\
-x              & , \text{if} \, x\leq 0   
  \end{cases}
$

I am trying to show it is a measurable function by showing $\{x\colon f(x)<a\}$ for all $a\in\Bbb R$.

Now, I will consider cases for $a$:

Case I: If $a\leq 0$, then $f^{-1}(-\infty,a)=(0,e^a).$

Case II: If $0<a<1$, then $f^{-1}(0,a)=(-a,0)\cup(1,e^a)$

Case III: If $a\geq 1$, then $f^{-1}(1,a)=(-a,1)$

Another way to do it, let $g_1(x)=\begin{cases}
   1 & ,\text{if } x=e \\
   0       & ,\text{if} \, x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{e\}\\   
  \end{cases}
$
, $g_2(x)=\begin{cases}
   1 & ,\text{if } x\in(0,e) \\
   0       & ,\text{if} \, x\in\Bbb R\setminus(0,e)\\   
  \end{cases}
$
, $g_3(x)=\begin{cases}
   1 & ,\text{if } x\in(-\infty,0] \\
   0       & ,\text{if} \, x\in\Bbb R\setminus(-\infty,0]\\   
  \end{cases}
$

Now, $f(x)=g_1(x)+\ln(x)g_2-xg_3(x).$ Clearly, $f$ is a measurable function.

Is that right?

Comment: Your definition of $f$ is unclear. What value takes $f(x)$ if $x\in(0,e)$?

Comment: @drhab, thank you for your comment. It was a typo. How about now?

Comment: I still miss $f(x)$ for $x>e$.

Comment: @drhab, it was typo too. I fixed it

Comment: You start with "promising" that $\{x: f(x)<a\}$ are to be checked (which is indeed enough). But in cases II and III you check the sets $\{x: 0<f(x)<a\}$ and $\{x: 1<f(x)<a\}$ respectively. A bit messy.

Comment: You could simplify the definition by stating that $f(x)=-x$ if $x\leq0$ and $f(x)=\ln(x)$ otherwise (note that $\ln(e)=1$).

Comment: @drhab, by a bit messy, you meant I can do 2 and 3 just as one case. Also, does the other way work as well